# Nginx rewriting urls with PHP

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to migrate from apache to an nginx and i'm encountering some issue with URL rewriting.
This is theexample's root structure:

- root

1. dir-1
2. dir-2
3. index.php
4. do.php
5. desc.ini
6. .hidden

- dir-1

1. file-1.php
2. file-2.php

I'm trying to achive these results:

```
 1. http://url/dir-1 -> 404 error
 2. http://url/dir-1/ -> 404 error
 3. http://url/dir-1/file-1.php -> 404 error
 4. http://url/dir-1/file-2.php -> 404 error
 5. http://url/desc.ini -> 404 error
 6. http://url/.hidden -> 404 error
 7. http://url/ -> 404 error
 8. http://url/index.php -> 404 error
 9. http://url/do.php -> 404 error
 10. http://url/<param1>/<param2> -> rewrite: http://url/do.php?p1=<param1>&p2=<param2>
 11. http://url/<param1>/<param2>/ -> rewrite: http://url/do.php?p1=<param1>&p2=<param2>
 12. http://url/<[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}> -> rewrite: http://url/index.php?p3=<[a-zA-Z0-9]>
 13. http://url/<[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}>/ -> rewrite: http://url/index.php?p3=<[a-zA-Z0-9]>
```

For now i succesffully did step 10 to 13, but when i try to do others, these files are downloadable.
Obviously this structure is only an example and i'm trying to achive general rules.

I post an example of nginx's configuration i'm trying.

Thank you!

```
server {
     listen <port>;
     listen [::]:<port>;
     server_name <url>;
     root <path1>;
     index <path1>;
     error_page 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 421 422 423 424 425 426 428 429 431 451 500 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 510 511 @error;

     location @error {
             try_files $uri $uri /error.html;
     }
     location ~ \.ini {
             rewrite /.*\.ini /error.html;
     }
     location ~ \.[a-zA-Z0-9]* {
             rewrite /\.[a-zA-Z0-9]* /error.html;
     }
     location ~ /(<param1>)/(<param2>)[/$] {
             try_files $uri $uri/ /do.php?p1=$1&p2=$2;
     }
     location ~ /([a-zA-Z0-9]*)[/$] {
         try_files $uri $uri /index.php?p3=$1;
     }
     location ~ \.php {
         try_files $uri =404;
         include <path2>/fastcgi_params;
         include <path2>/fastcgi.conf;
         fastcgi_pass unix:<path3>/php7.3-fpm.sock;
         fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
     }
}
```

Comment: Am I understand correctly that you want to generate 404 error on all requests except `http://url/<param1>/<param2>` and `http://url/<[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}>` with or without the trailing slash?

Comment: Yes, something's like that

Answer (score 1):

So if what you need is

- process `http://sitename/<param1>/<param2>` and `http://sitename/<param1>/<param2>/` requests with `do.php` script as `http://sitename/do.php?p1=<param1>&p2=<param2>`
- process `http://url/<[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}>` and `http://url/<[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}>/` requests with `index.php` script as `http://sitename/index.php?p3=<[a-zA-Z0-9]>{10}`
- generate an HTTP 404 error in all other cases

and there are no static content needs to be served, there is a much more simple way to do it without any rewrites:

```
server {
    listen <port>;
    listen [::]:<port>;
    server_name <sitename>;

    # you don't need neither 'root' nor 'index' directives

    # error page definition taken from Tom Nguyen answer
    error_page 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 421 422 423 424 425 426 428 429 431 451 500 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 510 511 /error.html;

    # serve 'http://sitename/<param1>/<param2>' requests
    # regexes for <param1> and <param2> should be changed to something meaningful, i.e.
    # (param1_possible_value1|param1_possible_value2|...) or ([a-zA-Z0-9]+) for any value
    location ~ ^/(<param1>)/(<param2>)/?$ {
        # initialize FastCGI parameters with default values first
        include fastcgi_params;
        # overwrite QUERY_STRING FastCGI parameter with a new value
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING p1=$1&p2=$2;
        # hardcode executable script path and name
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME <root_path>/do.php;
        # make FastCGI call
        fastcgi_pass unix:<socket_path>/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    }

    # serve 'http://sitename/<[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}>' requests
    # similar to the previous location block
    location ~ ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]{10})/?$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING p3=$1;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME <root_path>/index.php;
        fastcgi_pass unix:<socket_path>/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    }

    # all other requests should lead to HTTP 404 error
    location / {
        return 404;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Handle errors:**

The `location @error` block is redundant. Try to replace the following:

```
     error_page 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 421 422 423 424 425 426 428 429 431 451 500 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 510 511 @error;

     location @error {
             try_files $uri $uri /error.html;
     }
```

with:

```
    error_page 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 421 422 423 424 425 426 428 429 431 451 500 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 510 511 /error.html;
```

Read more about the `error_page` directive [here](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page).

**Handle rules 1 to 7:**

```
 1. http://url/dir-1 -> 404 error
 2. http://url/dir-1/ -> 404 error
 3. http://url/dir-1/file-1.php -> 404 error
 4. http://url/dir-1/file-2.php -> 404 error
 5. http://url/desc.ini -> 404 error
 6. http://url/.hidden -> 404 error
 7. http://url/ -> 404 error
```

Use the following:

```
    location = /dir-1 {
        return 404;
    }
    location = /dir-1/ {
        return 404;
    }
    location = /dir-1/file-1.php {
        return 404;
    }
    location = /dir-1/file-2.php {
        return 404;
    }
    location = /desc.ini {
        return 404;
    }
    location = /.hidden {
        return 404;
    }
    location = / {
        return 404;
    }
```

**Handle rules 8 and 9:**

```
 8. http://url/index.php -> 404 error
 9. http://url/do.php -> 404 error
```

These rules are a bit tricky as rules 10 to 13 are involved.

Use the following:

```
    location = /index.php {
        if ($is_args = "") {
            return 404;
        }

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
    location = /do.php {
        if ($is_args = "") {
            return 404;
        }

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
```

**Handle rules 10 to 13:**

```
 10. http://url/<param1>/<param2> -> rewrite: http://url/do.php?p1=<param1>&p2=<param2>
 11. http://url/<param1>/<param2>/ -> rewrite: http://url/do.php?p1=<param1>&p2=<param2>
 12. http://url/<[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}> -> rewrite: http://url/index.php?p3=<[a-zA-Z0-9]>
 13. http://url/<[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}>/ -> rewrite: http://url/index.php?p3=<[a-zA-Z0-9]>
```

Use the following:

```
    location ~ /(param1)/(param2)/?$ {
        rewrite ^ /do.php?p1=$1&p2=$2;
    }
    location ~ /([a-zA-Z0-9]{10})/?$ {
        rewrite ^ /index.php?p3=$1;
    }
```

**Final configuration:**

It should look something like this:

```
server {
    listen <port>;
    listen [::]:<port>;
    server_name <url>;
    root <path1>;
    index <path1>;

    error_page 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 421 422 423 424 425 426 428 429 431 451 500 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 510 511 /error.html;

    location = /dir-1 {
        return 404;
    }
    location = /dir-1/ {
        return 404;
    }
    location = /dir-1/file-1.php {
        return 404;
    }
    location = /dir-1/file-2.php {
        return 404;
    }
    location = /desc.ini {
        return 404;
    }
    location = /.hidden {
        return 404;
    }
    location = / {
        return 404;
    }

    location = /index.php {
        if ($is_args = "") {
            return 404;
        }

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
    location = /do.php {
        if ($is_args = "") {
            return 404;
        }

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~ /(param1)/(param2)/?$ {
        rewrite ^ /do.php?p1=$1&p2=$2;
    }
    location ~ /([a-zA-Z0-9]{10})/?$ {
        rewrite ^ /index.php?p3=$1;
    }

    location ~ \.php {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include <path2>/fastcgi_params;
        include <path2>/fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:<path3>/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

**Tip:**

If you want Nginx to respond to all PHP requests except `/index.php` and `/do.php`, keep the following:

```
    location ~ \.php {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include <path2>/fastcgi_params;
        include <path2>/fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:<path3>/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
```

If not, replace it with:

```
    location ~ \.php {
        return 404;
    }
```